# The new size can not be saved

Tags: magento2

I added new sizes, filled the entire list. When trying to save it receives an error. Does anyone know how to solve it.

```
Admin is a required field in the each row.
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Magento you are at? Do you have a size as 0? What all different options you have in admin column?

Comment: @Taran I have latest version magento 2.2.3. In admin column I have all sizes from XS to 3XL and "One Size" (example for watches). Impossible to save after add new size. When I only edit existing
field is possible to save.

Comment: What is the new size value you are trying to add?

Comment: Please check our movie: https://streamable.com/1xas6